# 2 input files in one form

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to have something like the following

```
<form id="uploadForm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>Upload File 1</p>
<input type="file" name="profile"/>
<p>Upload File 2</p>
<input type="file" name="cover"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I then have some php script looking like:

```
if (empty($_POST['save']) === false) {

// FOR PROFIL CHANGE
if (isset($_FILES['profile']) === true){
$allowed= array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'bmp');

$file_name = $_FILES['profile']['name']; //name of the file
$file_exts = explode('.', $file_name); // extension of the file
$file_extn = strtolower(end($file_exts)); //inlowercase
$file_temp = $_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'];
$id = $user_data['id'];
change_image2($id, $file_temp, $file_extn);
}
// FOR COVER CHANGE
if (isset($_FILES['cover']) === true){
$allowed= array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'bmp');

$file_name = $_FILES['cover']['name']; //name of the file
$file_exts = explode('.', $file_name); // extension of the file
$file_extn = strtolower(end($file_exts)); //inlowercase
$file_temp = $_FILES['cover']['tmp_name'];
$id = $user_data['id'];
change_image3($id, $file_temp, $file_extn);

}
```

But if I upload just one file ( cover for example ); it is saved also in profile for some reason ...
If find this weird because i gave different names to the inputs.
Can anybody explain the problem please?

Comment: `ashx` is php? looks like .net

Comment: looks like problem is in `change_image2` or `change_image3` methods

Comment: @Lashane Ignore the action="upload.ashx"; its action=""; i have edited sorry

Comment: @Lashane i don't think they is any problems with change_image2 and 3 functions. Because if i **only** add a file on cover for example (function_image3), it shouldn't even execute the change_image2 function as i didn't upload any profil files. But it is executing change_image2 and using the info from cover upload file .

Comment: why do you think that it executes change_image2? maybe your changed_image3 updates wrong field in database?

Answer (score 0):

Use `print_r($_FILES)` to check what data you receive when only one file is uploaded.

I think `$_FILES['profile']` is always set, no matter if a file is uploaded using the corresponding `<INPUT>` element or not. You should check if `$_FILES['profile']['name']` contains the file name or is empty.

You must also use [`is_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) (and [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)) with `$_FILES['profile']['tmp_name']` to handle the file.

`is_uploaded_file()` is the only [authoritative answer](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) to the question: *"did the user uploaded a file using this `<input>` control?"*

```
// FOR PROFIL CHANGE
if (! empty($_FILES['profile']['name'])
     && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'])){

    // ... process the file ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition from `if (isset($_FILES['profile']) === true){` into `if (strlen($_FILES['profile']['tmp_name']) > 0){`.
There will be always `$_FILES['profile']`, but `$_FILES['profile']['tmp_name']` contains some data only if there is some file transfer.